# Rails application route cannot access from Grape API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

I'm requesting for any user from a different rails application. I'm using `grape` gem. The below code is the requested user's information sending controller action.

but unfortunately it is showing error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `profile_url' for #<Grape::Endpoint:0xdadef8c>):
```

What is the problem? My `rake routes` showing the url does exists.

```
module V1
  class User < Grape::API
    version 'v1', using: :path
    format :json
    prefix :api

    resource :user do

      desc "find any user"

      params do
        requires :email, type: String
        requires :password, type: String
      end

      get :create do
        user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
        if user.present?
          if user.valid_password?(params[:password])
            {user: user, profile_url: profile_url(user.profile)}
          else
            {:notice => "Invalid password for email: #{params[:email]}"}
          end
        else
          {:notice => "No user found with email: #{params[:email]}"}
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

`rake routes | grep profile`:

```
profiles GET      /profiles(.:format)                                  profiles#index
                                                  POST     /profiles(.:format)                                                   profiles#create
                                      new_profile GET      /profiles/new(.:format)                                               profiles#new
                                     edit_profile GET      /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                                          profiles#edit
                                          profile GET      /profiles/:id(.:format)                                               profiles#show
                                                  PATCH    /profiles/:id(.:format)                                               profiles#update
                                                  PUT      /profiles/:id(.:format)                                               profiles#update
                                                  DELETE   /profiles/:id(.:format)                                               profiles#destroy
```

Comment: can you share your result of `rake routes | grep profile`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you mounted the resource properly.

You may need something like this:

```
mount API::v1::User
```

See more about [mounting here](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#mounting)

Also, take a look at this [post](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/making-a-rails-api-with-grap/). Might be helpful to see how you can mount your resource while using `Grape` gem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.profile_url(user.profile)
```